# How Do I Define One-to-Zero-Or-One Relationships in EF Core with Identity and Clean Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, clean-architecture

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application in .NET 5.0 using EF Core 5 with Identity for authentication/authorisation and I'm attempting to do this with a 'Clean Architecture'.

The application implements 3 'types' of user: Supervisors, Owners and Staff. Each are separate entities and so are persisted in their own db tables. Each user type has further related tables not shown here.

`ApplicationUser` (the principle entity, stored in the `AspNetUsers` table) needs a one-to-zero-or-one relationship to each of these user 'types' (the dependent entities):

```
//
// Infrastructure
//
namespace MyApp.Identity
{
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
  {
    ...
  }
}

//
// Core
//
namespace MyApp.Domain.Entities
{
  public class Supervisor
  {
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string Department { get; set; }
    
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } // FK
    ...
  }

  public class Owner
  {
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; } // FK
    ...
  }

  public class Staff
  {
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; } // FK
    ...
  }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` is in the `Identity` project within the Infrastructure layer as it is  implementation specific (as it inherits from `IdentityUser`).

To avoid going against the clean architecture principles, I shouldn't allow EF Core to automatically setup the relationships by convention because I believe that would require the addition of an `ApplicationUser` navigation property to the `Staff` entity, which in turn would require a reference to the infrastructure layer?

Hence, it appears I need to use Fluent API but how do I define these one-to-zero-or-one relationships without having the navigation properties please?

Comment: Navigation property is not an issue since it is not mandatory for defining a relationship (each relationship could have 0, 1 or 2 navigation properties). However the fluent configuration code still needs access to `ApplicationUser` in order to be able to configure the relationship. Because it needs to know the type of principal table, right? How that fits in "clean" or whatever architecture is the problem of that architecture, not EF Core. IMHO any architecture which instead of helping creates abstract problems and leading to non natural solutions...

Comment: ... (and the most natural way to represent relationship in OO way are navigation properties at both sides) is not a good architecture.

Comment: Yes, the ASP.Net identity model is better left alone. I even think that its extensibility is an architectural flaw (OK, maybe except choosing PK column types). So the recommended way to go about this is to have some `ApplicationUser` table in the business part of the database that refers to `AspNetUsers`, (but only in the database as a unique FK field, not in the EF model). Then you can do anything you like with this `ApplicationUser` table. That keeps authentication and BL nicely apart. Speaking about clean...

Comment: Yes, @IvanStoev - thanks for your comment - I agree. Been wrestling with this for a while now and I am yet to figure out a seamless solution when using Identity within a clean architecture...

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. I coming to a similar conclusion - currently the best way forward is to not have any relationships defined by EF Core between the ApplicationUser entity (which is ultimately persisted into AspNetUsers) and my user entities (Supervisor, Owner and Staff) but use the AspNetUser.Id PK GUID column that is generated by ASP.NET Core Identity as a FK column in the Supervisor, Owner and Staff entities and maintain this relationship in my own code. Seems a bit of a hack but haven't yet come across a better solution... 8-|

Answer (score 4):

You have two probelms to sove here.

First one is how to map the relationships in your database to your application model without navigation properties.

Second is how to map the relationship between IdentityUser and other specific users in your model, keeping `MyApp.Identity` isolated from your model.

1 - To map a hieraquial relationship in EF and each object with their own table, yout should use [Table Per Type (TPT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration) configuration. I'll not explain it here, but I will leave an example code bellow. If need more information about TPT look the links at the end of my answer. [And be aware that TPT in many cases shows inferior performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/modeling-for-performance#inheritance-mapping)
1.1 You will have to create a base class `BaseUser` and all other user types should inhiret from it.
1.1.1 `BaseUser` also implements `IUser` it will be explained on item 2.
1.2 The `Id` property of each child of `BaseUser` will be PK and FK.

2 - This kind of isolation you want is easly acomplished with IoC (Inversion of Control) and DI (Dependency Injection).

2.1 Begin creating a interface that contains base information about your user, and is needed for all kinds of user. You should put at least the  `Id` property their.
2.2 Create an interface in your application layer to resolve `IUser` , I'll call it `IUserResolver`
2.2.1 For the example case `IUserResolver` will only contains one method, but you can have as many you want.
2.2.2 Just remember to do **not return any object from** `Identity`, **you should have your own types to represent the information you want to expose.**
2.3. Your `ApplicationUser` should inhiret from `IdentityUser<Guid>` and implements `IUser`
2.4. Create the concrete implemantation of `IUserResolver` on `MyApp.Identity`
2.4.1 Instead of return `IdentityUser` return `IUser`
2.5 On your IoC layer map the `IUserResolver` to `UserResolver`

Now anytime you need the currentUser on your application you junt need to get it from `IUserResolver`. using DI. The best part of it, is when next version of `AspNet.Identity` be released and we get some breaking changes, all your `Identity`  logic is isolated in just one project. Believe me, will have breking changes.

I have a few solutions like this one in production, and it works like a charm.

```cs
//
// Infrastructure
//
namespace MyApp.Identity
{
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>, IUser
  {
    ...
  }
  
  public class UserResolver : IUserResolver
  {
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _user;


        public UserResolver(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _user = accessor.HttpContext.User;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<IUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
        {
            if (!_user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return null;
            
            var userId = // get id from _user;
            return await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        }
        ...
  }
}

///
/// IoC
///
   services.AddScoped<IUserResolver, UserResolver>();

//
// Core
//
namespace MyApp.Domain.Contracts
{
  public interface IUser
  {
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     // ... Other commom properties between IdentityUser & BaseUser.
  }
  
  public interface IUserResolver
  {
      Task<IUser> GetCurrentUserAsync();
  }
}

namespace MyApp.Domain.Entities
{

  public class BaseUser : IUser
  {
     public Guid Id {get; set;} // Required
     public string UserName {get; set;} // Optional
     // ... Other optional properties. 
     // Avoid map specifc Identity properties
  }

  public class Supervisor : BaseUser
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK & FK
    public string Department { get; set; }
    
    ...
  }

  public class Owner : BaseUser
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK & FK
    public string Company { get; set; }

    ...
  }

  public class Staff : BaseUser
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK & FK
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    ...
  }
}

///
/// EF Mapping
///
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Supervisor>().ToTable("Supervisor");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().ToTable("Owner");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>().ToTable("Staff");
}

///
/// Handle this data
///
public SetUserAsSupervisor(IUser baseUser, string department)
{
    using (var context = new EntityContext())
  {
    Supervisor supervisor = (Supervisor)baseUser;
    supervisor.Department = "Marketing";
    
        context.BaseUser.Update(supervisor);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public SetUserAsOwner(IUser baseUser, string company)
{
    using (var context = new EntityContext())
  {
    Owner onwer = (Owner)baseUser;
    onwer.Company = "Microsoft";
    
        context.BaseUser.Update(onwer);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

#### Usefull Links:

##### TPT

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration
https://entityframework.net/tpt
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/whats-new-in-ef-core-5/table-per-type-tpt-mapping